# Custom callbacks in VBA

Tags: vba, callback

Note the tag: **VBA**, not VB6, not VB.NET.

This is specific to VBA in MS Access. I've built a collection of methods in an module I call "Enumerable". It does a lot of things reminiscent of the Enumerable classes and interfaces in .NET. One thing I want to implement is a ForEach method, analagous to the .NET [**Enumerable.Select method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

I built a version that uses the [**Application.Run**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214047(v=office.12).aspx) method to call a function for each element, but Application.Run only works with user-defined methods. For example, the following works:

```
' User-defined wrapper function:
Public Function MyReplace( _
    Expression As String, Find As String, StrReplace As String, _
    Optional Start As Long = 1, _
    Optional Count As Long = 1, _
    Optional Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare)
    MyReplace = Replace(Expression, Find, StrReplace, Start, Count, Compare)
End Function

' Using Application.Run to call a method by name
Public Sub RunTest()
    Debug.Print Run("MyReplace", "Input", "In", "Out")
End Sub
```

RunTest prints "Output", as expected. The following does NOT work:

```
Debug.Print Run("Replace", "Input", "In", "Out")
```

It throws run-time error 430: "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface". This is expected, because the documentation states that Application.Run only works for user-defined methods.

VBA does have an AddressOf operator, but that only works when passing function pointers to external API functions; function pointers created using AddressOf are not consumable in VBA. Again, this is noted in the documentation (or see for example [**VBA - CallBacks = Few Cents Less Than A Dollar?**](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware4/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=140196&ixReplies=19)).

So is there any other way to identify and call a method using a variable? Or will my callback-ish attempts be limited to user-defined functions via the Application.Run method?

Comment: You wont be able to use addressof, but VBA supports classes so interface based callbacks are fine; `sub something(arg as string, myCallBack as IWhatever) ... myCallBack.call(...)` Stuff your methods into a class and you can invoke them by name with "CallByName" - its a bit weak due to the handling of dynamic numbers of arguments, an alternative http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15422

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you actually need help with. Your first paragraph talks about implementing `For...Each` but the rest of your question talks about trying to use `Application.Run` on a VBA function.

Comment: @mischab1 - Take a look at any of the .NET IEnumerable extension methods. In most of them you provide a callback to execute on each member of a collection. I'm trying to do the same thing in VBA. VBA does not have delegates or function pointers or anything. I've used Application.Run as a substitute, but it has limited applicability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No other answers in a week...for resolution's sake here's the best I could come up with:

1. I built a helper module that resolves a ParamArray to individual arguments for the sake of calling `CallByName`. If you pass a ParamArray through to `CallByName` it will mash all the arguments into a single, actual `Array` and pass that to the first argument in the method you attempt to invoke.
2. I built two `ForEach` methods: one that invokes `Application.Run`, and another that invokes `CallByName`. As noted in the question, `Application.Run` only works for user-defined global (public module) methods. In turn, `CallByName` only works on instance methods, and requires an object argument.

That still leaves me without a way to directly invoke built-in global methods (such as `Trim()`) by name. My workaround for that is to build user-defined wrapper methods that just call the built-in global method, for example:

```
Public Function FLeft( _
   str As String, _
   Length As Long) As String
    FLeft = Left(str, Length)
End Function

Public Function FLTrim( _
   str As String) As String
    FLTrim = LTrim(str)
End Function

Public Function FRight( _
   str As String, _
   Length As Long) As String
    FRight = Right(str, Length)
End Function

...etc...
```

I can now use these to do things like:

```
' Trim all the strings in an array of strings
trimmedArray = ForEachRun(rawArray, "FTrim")

' Use RegExp to replace stuff in all the elements of an array
' --> Remove periods that aren't between numbers
Dim rx As New RegExp
rx.Pattern = "(^|\D)\.(\D|$)"
rx.Global = True
resultArray = ForEachCallByName(inputArray, rx, "Replace", VbMethod, "$1 $2")
```

Comment: You mean, `FLTrim` here `trimmedArray = ForEachRun(rawArray, "FTrim")`?

Comment: @bonCodigo No, `Trim` and `LTrim` are separate VBA functions. In the top code I show example of the wrapper for `LTrim`, and the lower example I use the wrapper for `Trim`.

Comment: I have a couple of alternative suggestions, would you still be interested in answers to the question?

Comment: @Blackhawk, I just found this question via a search engine, so I guess it's safe to assume the answer is *yes*, someone will be interested

Comment: @user357269 For an implementation of first class functions in VBA (as in, functions which can be stored in variables, passed to functions, and called anonymously), see [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138557/functional-framework).

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but for those looking for a more general approach please use `stdCallback` and `stdLambda` alongside `stdICallable`. These can be found as part of the [`stdVBA`](http://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA) library (a library largely maintained by myself).

```
sub Main()
  'Create an array
  Dim arr as stdArray
  set arr = stdArray.Create(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 'Can also call CreateFromArray

  'Demonstrating join, join will be used in most of the below functions
  Debug.Print arr.join()                                                 '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
  Debug.Print arr.join("|")                                              '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10

  'Basic operations
  arr.push 3
  Debug.Print arr.join()                                                 '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3
  Debug.Print arr.pop()                                                  '3
  Debug.Print arr.join()                                                 '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
  Debug.Print arr.concat(stdArray.Create(11,12,13)).join                 '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13
  Debug.Print arr.join()                                                 '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 'concat doesn't mutate object
  Debug.Print arr.includes(3)                                            'True
  Debug.Print arr.includes(34)                                           'False

  'More advanced behaviour when including callbacks! And VBA Lamdas!!
  Debug.Print arr.Map(stdLambda.Create("$1+1")).join          '2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
  Debug.Print arr.Reduce(stdLambda.Create("$1+$2"))           '55 ' I.E. Calculate the sum
  Debug.Print arr.Reduce(stdLambda.Create("Max($1,$2)"))      '10 ' I.E. Calculate the maximum
  Debug.Print arr.Filter(stdLambda.Create("$1>=5")).join      '5,6,7,8,9,10
  
  'Execute property accessors with Lambda syntax
  Debug.Print arr.Map(stdLambda.Create("ThisWorkbook.Sheets($1)")) _ 
                .Map(stdLambda.Create("$1.Name")).join(",")            'Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,...,Sheet10
  
  'Execute methods with lambdas and enumerate over enumeratable collections:
  Call stdEnumerator.Create(Application.Workbooks).forEach(stdLambda.Create("$1#Save")
  
  'We even have if statement!
  With stdLambda.Create("if $1 then ""lisa"" else ""bart""")
    Debug.Print .Run(true)                                              'lisa
    Debug.Print .Run(false)                                             'bart
  End With
  
  'Execute custom functions
  Debug.Print arr.Map(stdCallback.CreateFromModule("ModuleMain","CalcArea")).join  '3.14159,12.56636,28.274309999999996,50.26544,78.53975,113.09723999999999,153.93791,201.06176,254.46879,314.159
  
  'Creating from an object property
  Debug.Print arr.Map(stdCallback.CreateFromObjectProperty(arr,"item", vbGet))  '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

  'Creating from an object method
  Debug.Print arr.Map(stdCallback.CreateFromObjectMethod(someObj,"getStuff"))
End Sub

Public Function CalcArea(ByVal radius as Double) as Double
  CalcArea = 3.14159*radius*radius
End Function
```