GetRef() in vba throws Compile error: Sub or Function not defined
I just want to use GetRef, didnt work, even in the simplest example:
Why?
Sub CallbackFunction(message As String)
  MsgBox "Callback Function Called With Message: " & message
End Sub

Sub Main()
  Dim callback As Variant
  Set callback = GetRef("CallbackFunction")
  callback "Hello, World!"
End Sub

Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Compile error:
Sub or Function not defined




Isn't GetRef a VBScript function? (not VBA)

@braX idk, some say its built in in vba?... Anyways, what if I need it in vba?

Maybe you can explain a little more what exactly you are trying to do by using it? It looks like maybe you wanted something like CallByName but I am not sure.

@braX The original purpose is to use Regexp with callback (GetRef) in VBA. see: >" Set replacement = getRef("Capitelize")
https://automated-chaos.blogspot.com/2012/02/using-callbacks-on-regexpreplace.html \ I got the simple regexp part worked by adding reference lib to vbscript regex. but not the getref part. \ Maybe you are right, I cannot do it in vba?

I would read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101433/8422953
